# Mouse doesn't work properly and random crashes

Tags: mouse, crash

I recently installed Ubuntu on my new computer and I have to say that it has been a kinda bad experience so far. I've actually been wanting to use it for a while as I've become more enlightened about windows and its flaws and seeing others use it but I must say I didn't expect the amount of trouble I would have to make it work. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I pretty much have had trouble with it from the beginning even when trying to install it. I used rufus to make a bootable USB drive following the tutorial on tutorials.ubuntu. The first many times the installer would keep making errors such that it couldn't install Ubuntu, it was only later when I found out that I had to use rufus DD mode to install it properly. But the problems didn't end there. After the installation I thought everything would work, but the first thing that happened after it booted was that the mouse wouldn't function correctly, it was impossible to use the mouse to click anywhere outside the window that had focus making it almost impossible to navigate around, I have not yet found a permanent fix to that but I found out that when I get the bug I need to logout and then login and it will work. Other than that I get random crashes, sometimes almost constantly (particularly firefox likes to crash but sometimes the whole system or games crash as well) and other times it can work for hours with no issues at all. I do not believe it is a hardware issue as my computer is only 3 weeks old. 
I would really like to find a solution because it is just unbearable to work on a computer like that, particularly when the reason I bought the new computer was because the old one had developed this problem (crashing not mouse problems). Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks in advance.

Update: So I tried disabling c-state control in the UEFI and setting power supply idle control to typical current idle which seems to have fixed my freezes and crashes. This is not ideal however as I mostly do light work and just want to save power. 
I still can't figure out what the problem with the mouse and windows locking is.

[My specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srnio.png)

Comment: In fact firefox crashed right now as i posted this question.

Comment: It would be perhaps enlightening to know what hardware you are using; also, near the end of your comments, you seemed to imply that the OLD COMPUTER had the same(mouse???) problems.  If this is in fact true, well, then...have you tried another mouse?

Comment: I only offered the try another mouse suggestion, but I should have added, it seems to be clear that there are other problems(firefox, games) as well.  Where did you get your download of 18.04?  Other questions come to mind.

Comment: I added a picture of my specs to my question, I can see how it could be the mouse thats the issue, but I don't think its the problem because it works on my laptop. Sadly I don't have another mouse to test with.

Comment: I downloaded the iso from ubuntus official website

Comment: Trying to anticipate your answers is not easy.  Thats the reason for asking other questions like this.  But here goes...what system came with your new computer and how smoothly was it running in that system before you attempted Ubuntu?  And, is your system now a dual-boot, or are you running 18.04 directly from the flash drive?  Or are you using(unlikely) something like virtualbox to run 18.04?

Comment: I never tried anything else than ubuntu because I lost my windows key (my old pc fucked up my HDD and I lost the original case with key on)

Comment: Im not using the HDD now by the way I'm using a new nvme drive

Comment: I build the system myself so it didn't come preinstalled with anything.

Comment: Mads, wow!  we've come a long way from your original question.  First off, there are some good components in there alright.  question begs, is this your first build?

Comment: Well, it is my first build if you don't consider reassembling my old pc and installing after market coolers on gpu's. :)

Comment: Alright, well you are going places I've only dreamt of going, so far!  Other question for ya.  You seem to imply that you were using a hdd and now use ssd in there.  What problems are worse since you made that change?  Ok I read some more and you had already replaced the hdd before trying 18.04 so I've answered that.  Could you have wiped the old hdd and tried 18.04 on that or did you just want an ssd?  well, we all do I suppose!

Comment: Gah, sorry for not answering i was writing something and then firefox crashed because i took too long to write. Ill try to see if i can get it done

Comment: My old computer from 2011 had worked perfectly up until a months time ago when it started crashing under the slightest workloads sometimes even during boot. I decided to buy new components at black friday so i bought new ram, cpu, gpu, nvme and motherboard and kept my (relatively) old psu from the other pc which i bought a year ago (rm 850x). I didn't bother using the old HDD because I tried to reinstall windows in case the problem was with software and not hardware but that didn't go well and the whole installation was "corrupted".

Comment: So basically I was going with ubuntu from the start, I made a bootable usb from my laptop and installed ubuntu on the nvme.

Comment: I have considered whether the psu was the culprit but it doesn't seem like it since this new pc draws more power than my old pc which was a 1000x more unstable.

Comment: Alright well, as far as my experience goes, it won't help you with your problem.  I am sorry, but I tried.  I hope others more experienced can help more.

Comment: Alright, thanks for taking your time to help though, it is appreciated :) Just one last thing though, in case it is the mouse that crashes the system, do you know if that is actually possible?

Comment: Not if, as you say, it works well on your laptop.  Not likely to be the bad guy in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

to fully help you, i need to know the computers name and year(as well as any changes from the stock GPU,CPU,RAM cards, etc). some basic troubleshooting for you would be to update BIOS,get drivers for everything(this is a common one), and if that doesnt help, then your pc may not be able to handle Ubuntu

Comment: Ok so I have updated to the latest bios and the problem persists.

Comment: I tried disabling c-state control and setting power supply idle control to typical current idle which seems to have fixed the freezing/crashing but im afraid that my electric bill will spiral out of proportions because of this. It didn't fix the mouse/window problem.

Comment: By computer name and year what exactly do you mean? Its a new pc i build in november. By stock hardware do you imply that i had an old computer that i changed the hardware in? In that case I didnt change anything as i build the pc from scratch.

Comment: https://www.servethehome.com/amd-ryzen-with-ubuntu-here-is-what-you-have-to-do-to-fix-constant-crashes/